# Alternative to appending inner joins in search query

Tags: sql, postgresql, inner-join

When searching for a post, the user is able to select from a list of categories to filter by, which returns the posts related to all categories selected.

```
SELECT *
FROM posts
INNER JOIN category_joins as filter_categories_join
  ON filter_categories_join.categorizable_id = posts.id 
  AND filter_categories_join.categorizable_type = 'Post'
INNER JOIN categories as filter_categories 
  ON filter_categories.id = filter_categories_join.category_id
INNER JOIN category_joins as categories_join_1
  ON categories_join_1.categorizable_id = posts.id
  AND categories_join_1.categorizable_type = 'Post'
INNER JOIN categories as categories_1
  ON categories_1.id = categories_join_1.category_id
INNER JOIN category_joins as categories_join_2
  ON categories_join_2.categorizable_id = posts.id
  AND categories_join_2.categorizable_type = 'Post'
INNER JOIN categories as categories_2
  ON categories_2.id = categories_join_2.category_id
WHERE filter_categories.lft BETWEEN 14 AND 115
  AND categories_1.lft BETWEEN 133 AND 134
  AND categories_2.lft BETWEEN 137 AND 138
```

Is there a way to avoid appending an inner join for each of these category filters?

UPDATE:

A description of the associations here:

- `posts` have many `categories`
- `posts` are related to `categories` through `category_joins` as categorizable
- `categories` have many `posts` through `category_joins`

Comment: You're forcing us to guess, please could you include example data and describe the behaviour structure of your data.  For example, I assume the join between `posts` and `category_joins` is `1:many`?  And that the join between `category_joins` and `filter_categories` is `1:1`?  You need to give a Whole Lot more information to get a complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are duplicating the `JOINS` which is unnecessary. Your query can be simplified to

```
SELECT p.*
FROM posts p
INNER JOIN category_joins cj
  ON cj.categorizable_id = p.id 
  AND cj.categorizable_type = 'Post'

INNER JOIN categories c
  ON c.id = cj.category_id
AND c.lft BETWEEN 14 AND 115
    INNER JOIN categories c1
  ON c1.id = cj.category_id
  AND c1.lft BETWEEN 133 AND 134
INNER JOIN categories c2
  ON c2.id = cj.category_id
 AND c2.lft BETWEEN 137 AND 138;
```